# C# Simple Calculator

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm practicing programming so I can be good at it but I cant finish this calculator code. I can't add, subtract, multiply or divide three or more numbers. Please help. What's wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculator
{

public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    int oprtn;
    String firstNumber;
    String nextNumber;

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtShow.Text = txtShow.Text + btn0.Text;
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtShow.Text = txtShow.Text + btn1.Text;
    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtShow.Text = txtShow.Text + btn2.Text;
    }

    private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtShow.Text = txtShow.Text + btn3.Text;
    }

    private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtShow.Text = txtShow.Text + btn4.Text;
    }

    private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtShow.Text = txtShow.Text + btn5.Text;
    }

    private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtShow.Text = txtShow.Text + btn6.Text;
    }

    private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtShow.Text = txtShow.Text + btn7.Text;
    }

    private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtShow.Text = txtShow.Text + btn8.Text;
    }

    private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtShow.Text = txtShow.Text + btn9.Text;
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtShow.Clear();
    }

    private void btnSubtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        firstNumber = txtShow.Text;
        oprtn = 2;
        txtShow.Text = "";            
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        firstNumber = txtShow.Text;

        oprtn = 1;
        txtShow.Text = "";
    }

    private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        firstNumber = txtShow.Text;
        oprtn = 4;
        txtShow.Text = "";  
    }

    private void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        firstNumber = txtShow.Text;
        oprtn = 3;
        txtShow.Text = "";           
    }


    private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nextNumber = txtShow.Text;
        int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(firstNumber);
        int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(nextNumber);


        switch (oprtn)
        {
            case 1:
                int sum = num1 + num2;
                String equals = Convert.ToString(sum);  
                sum = sum + num2;
                txtShow.Text = equals;
                break;
            case 2:
                int difference = num1 - num2;                  
                equals = Convert.ToString(difference);
                difference = difference - num2;
                txtShow.Text = equals;
                break;
            case 3:
                int product = num1 * num2;
                equals = Convert.ToString(product);
                product = product * num2;
                txtShow.Text = equals;
                break;
            case 4:
                int quotient = num1 / num2;                   
                equals = Convert.ToString(quotient);
                quotient = quotient / num2;
                txtShow.Text = equals;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void btnBackspace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void txtShow_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnPoint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtShow.Text = txtShow.Text + ".";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: *What's wrong with my code?* .... what's wrong with your code?

Comment: I cant add three or more numbers. (Example: 3+3+3)

Comment: Why not.. Do you get an exception, or the wrong result?

Comment: Here's a fully operative calculator: `new DataTable().Compute("1+5-7/5*3", null)`

Comment: It shouldn't compile anyway. What's `equals` variable in `btnEquals_Click` method? It isn't declared anywhere.

Comment: When I press 3+3+3 the answer is 6.

Comment: @pwas: I'm using it to display the answer on the textbox.

Comment: @paws: It is being declared in the first switch statement. Poor scoping.

Comment: lyang, your code is a little bit hard to follow but do you not just need to press the equals key once more?

Comment: @Sayse: What if I press 3+2+1? When I press 3(num1) then add 2(num2) then add 1(1 will be num2 and 2 will be num1).

Comment: @Sayse: If i add three different numbers. Its wrong -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current solution, you can't add more than two numbers without pressing = first.

What happens is this:

```
 >3
 //Number '3' is stored in txtShow.Text
 >3+
 //'3' is stored in nextNumber
 >3+3
 //Number '3' is stored in txtShow.Text again
 >3+3+
 //'3' is stored in nextNumber, overriding the first number
 >3+3+3
 //Number '3' is stored in txtShow.Text again
 >3+3+3=
 //Calculation is done, but nextNumber contains '3', and then 3 is added, yielding 6
```

Simplest solution is to perform the math every time you press an operator. So you need to calculate `3+3=6` first, then add another 3.